# Incompatible parameter Type, Workshop Actions

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I am trying to configure an action to create an instance in an object. But when I am giving an object reference for one of the properties in the form, it says Incompatible parameter types.

I checked the datatypes of these 2 strings and both of them are 'string', not sure why this message is getting displayed and I am not able to save my edits in ontology as well.

Comment: Hi Monsta, this is very hard to understand what could be going on wrong. Any chance you can share your rule definition and ontology object that you are mapping? (do remember you are in a public space so please redact any naming or other confidential things)